Zero knowledge proof of a linear expression in the exponent
Alice sends to Bob a value $B$ in $\mathbb{G}$ a group of high order. There are distinct elements $h_1$ and $h_2$ of high order of $\mathbb{G}$, and Alice wants to prove to Bob that she knows some values $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ such that $B=h_1^{b_1}h_2^{b_2}$.
I have found the following related post (quite old and without answer), but I could not find any information about the mentioned Okamoto protocol.
1/ Is this kind of proof possible and what are the techniques used in the literature to construct such a zero knowledge proof of knowledge?
2/ Is the Okamoto protocol in the related post correct? Where can we find information about it?

What research have you done? What have you found and tried?

@e-sushi I am not aware about the techniques we could use. Some pointers, courses, videos, could help

Note: If I understand the question correctly, it's about Zero knowledge proof of knowledge of coefficients in a linear expression. The term linear becomes clearer is we rewrite the expression $B=h_1^{b_1}h_2^{b_2}$ with the group $\mathbb G$ noted additively rather than multiplicatively. The problem then is proving knowledge of scalars $b_1$ and $b_2$ such that $B=b_1\cdot H_1+b_2\cdot H_2$, without disclosing anything about these $b_1$ and $b_2$. (continued)

With that additive notation, the protocol proposed in the related post is: Prover picks random secret $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb Z_q$, sends $A=r_1\cdot H_1+r_2\cdot H_2$. Verifier picks and sends random $c\in\mathbb Z_q$. Prover computes and sends $z_1=r_1+c,b_1\bmod q$,  $z_2=r_2+c,b_2\bmod q$. Verifier checks that $z_1\cdot H_1+z_2\cdot H_2=A+c\cdot B$, and if that holds accepts that prover knows $b_1$ and $b_2$. I'm not able to answer the question (in particular I fail to decide if this proof is "zero-knowledge").

Thank you @fgrieu

Search "Okamoto protocol" in google(quotation involved), you can find the lecture notes and some other slides.
So the Okamoto protocol is a WI and WH protocol, but not ZK. Besides, it's also HVZK, but not ZK. You can also have a reference here.

Thanks very much Yang. Why do you say it is not ZK? Are you referring to the malicious setting? I am new in this topic. But I have read somewhere that any hvzk proof can be transformed into something ZK in the malicious setting by way of a FS transform.

@Adam54 Yes. I mean malicious verifier, who may deviate the protocol. You are right there is some general method from HVZK to ZK(like it in sec 8). But I think what you want is not FS transform. Because FS outputs a non-interactive ZK under random oracle model( FS always used to get a signature scheme from a identification scheme). So you can do some transform, but that's a new protocol. The okamoto's protocol is ZK only against honest verifier.
